# How do I create clickable text that executes a command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want a line of text to appear in the chat, that when clicked on will execute a `/fill` command.

I have used the following command to no avail: (~ = desired message or command)

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"~","clickEvent":{"action":run_command","value":"/~"}}
```

This command seems like it would work, but it says that it needs an "array."

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ tellraw @p {"nbt":"","storage":"Why would I do that?","italic":true,"underlined":true,"color":"yellow","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/fill <> <to> <block>"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in Bedrock Edition, only in Java Edition.  Raw JSON text is [much more limited in Bedrock Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format#Bedrock_Edition), so much so that you can't even change the color or other formatting using JSON tags (you should still be able to use [formatting codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes)), much less use the interactive features that make `tellraw` so powerful in Java Edition.

Comment: So it seems you can [change](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/swift/tellraw+command+minecraft+bedrock) [the color](https://www.colorschemer.com/minecraft-color-codes/), but it doesn't use the JSON formatting that Java Edition uses.  Still can't change the style though, unless I missed something.  This is some documentation detail that's missing from the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

### There might be a simple way

I haven't tested this out but it is an idea you can look into. If you place a sign down, type whatever you like with whatever color tags, then behind it, have a comparator facing outward behind the block holding the sign. Then have a commandblock on the output side of that comparator. You right-click on the sign as if you wanted to use it. The sign might emit change significant enough to be picked up by the comparator.

Comment: Thanks, that might be pretty helpful. I probably should have clarified this, but I am looking for clickable text specifically in the chat. But thank you, I will probably use this in the future.