# Teleporter pad command Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am new to command blocks, and was wondering if a block in the floor topped with a pressure plate and coded with this code would work as a teleporter between tower floors, where the player just walks on it and clicks which floor name to go to for compact teleporting:

```
scoreboard players enable @a question 
/tellraw @a ["",{"text":"Where to?"
,"color":"gold","bold":"true"},{"text":"LOCATION NAME1","color":"green","bold":"true","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger question set 1"}},{"text":"LOCATION NAME2","color":"none","bold":"true","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger question set 2"}},{"text":"LOCATION NAME3","color":"red","bold":"true","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger question set 3"}}] 
execute @a[score_question=1] /tp @p × × ×
execute @a[score_question_min=2] /tp @p × × ×
execute @a[score_question_min=3] /tp @p × × ×
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create clickable text that executes a command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374671/how-do-i-create-clickable-text-that-executes-a-command)

Comment: That is, assuming MCBE is actually being played; the asker posted what looks like a Java-Edition-style tellraw and tagged it [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition].

Comment: @pppery You appear to be correct. The `/execute` commands in the question are MCBE "old-style" `/execute` commands. It is highly likely that the asker mixed up the JSON text with Java's format.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to type all of those commands, Just give yourself a sign with this command:

```
/give @p oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"LocationName\",\"color\":\"black\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/tp @s (cordinates) (rotation)\"}}",id:"Sign"}}
```

After that if you right click on that sign you will teleport in the cordinates you've selected. **(@s means who is clicking the sign.)**

Comment: This looks like a Java Edition command on a Bedrock Edition question.